# log imap server conversation with email client

Tags: thunderbird, imap, yahoo-mail

Is there a way to get the server responses from yahoo's imap server when downloading messages, deleting messages and searching.

I tried getting them with wireshark, but everything is behind TLS. This is for an  email address I own.

The email client is thunderbird. I couldn't find a plugin that lets me see the request and response commands unfortunately.

I am open to using another email client or software to get the imap commands recorded.

Comment: I'm not a thunderbird user, but in my mail client (eMClient) you can turn on logging for IMAP. Worth a look.

Comment: I took a look at the website, is logging available in both the free and the paid version?

Comment: Yes, paid version is the same but for businesses and more than 2 accounts added at once + support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Thunderbird supports this.

However, I use eMClient, and it allows you to log all SMTP, IMAP and POP traffic.

You can get it free from here: [eMClient](http://www.emclient.com/)

Here's how you can configure logging on IMAP/POP/SMTP protocol level:

1. go to S*ettings/Preferences*
2. select *Advanced > Logging*
3. scroll down to the mail account
4. check *IMAP/POP/SMTP*

The location of the log file is given (and can be changed) under *Logging directory*.

Comment: So much easier to get an IMAP log from this client than from Thunderbird!

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging describes how to capture the data you are looking for

Comment: I tried that its not logging anything to the file it creates, windows 8.1 pro, 64 bit,

Comment: see https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging#Missing_Log_File

Comment: I decided to read the wiki above again, and discovered something interesting. I am using mozilla thunderbird portable and it uses the old entries instead of MOZ_LOG and MOZ_FILE.     `set NSPR_LOG_MODULES=IMAP:5,timestamp
set NSPR_LOG_FILE=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\imap.log
"C:\Users\lid\ThunderbirdPortable\ThunderbirdPortable.exe"`